# How do I make a .txt read in python to work with an if statement for a new line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need help with this code as I don't know where I've gone wrong with this as I want the if statement to read abc first then def after so then it can say access granted. Here is the code below:

```
file=open("test.txt","r")
username = input("enter username")
if file.read() == username:
    print("Enter password")
else:
 print("enter password")
password = input()
if file.read() == password:
 print ("acsess granted")
else:
    print ("access denied")
```

Here is the text file contents:

```
abc
def
```

The problem that I'm getting with this is that it will always output `access denied` where as both abc and def have been in both separate lines. I have used `f.readlines()` however this also outputs the same message. Putting a `\n` in the code will result in this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/boys/Documents/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    if file.read('\n') == password:
TypeError: integer argument expected, got 'str'
```

Note: I will have to have more than one username and password for this, and a admin username and admin password.

Comment: I think you might want `file.readline()` instead.

Comment: I have done this, however it will still output with 'access denied'

Comment: Does `file.readline()` include the trailing newline? I don't know off the top of my head, but that would cause that behavior.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean `file.readline()` might give `"abc"` or it might give `"abc\n"`, I'm not sure without double checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `readline()` includes the newline (`\n`) at the end. The `splitlines()` function is one way to work around this:

```
file=open("test.txt","r")
text = file.read().splitlines()
username = input("enter username")
if text[0] == username:
    print("Enter password")
    password = input()
    if text[1] == password:
        print ("acsess granted")
    else:
        print ("access denied")
else:
    print("Wrong username!")
```

EDIT: I also fixed the logic so that an incorrect password but correct username no longer prints "access granted" (which I assume was not the OP's intended beahvior).

Comment: If you do this, you should just unpack directly. `f_user, f_pass = file.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Though it's *probably* faster to readlines and map over str.strip. `f_user, f_pass = map(lambda s: s.rstrip("\n"), file.readlines())`

Comment: Yes, both of those are good suggestions. Given the nature of the question, I tried to provide the simplest answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code has a security issue - your user is able to recognize correct username *without yet entering a password*.

Second, it is a little complicated, so I give you another one

```
with open("test.txt") as inp:
    u_name = inp.readline()
    p_word = inp.readline()

username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")

if username == u_name.strip() and password == p_word.strip():
    print("Access granted")
else:
    print("Access denied")
```

**Some explanation:**

Use a *context manager* (`with`) instead of direct `open()` - it safely closes your file in all situations and gives you other advantages.

`"r"` is the default, so you may omit it in `open()` function.

`strip()` function strips out *whitespace symbols* (spaces, tabs, newlines, ...) from both ends of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on Brendan's post, but I still don't have enough rep to add comments, so I'm throwing this into an answer.

A couple other corrections I would suggest is to use RAW_INPUT() over INPUT(), so that you don't need to include quotes when entering in your information. RAW_INPUT assumes a string, while input assumes a number or variable if the quotes are not included.

Also, your first **else** statement is misleading you (from a validation standpoint). While testing your code, you should have them saying something a little different, maybe adding a number indicator to see which part of the statement the logic hit.

Comment: It's `raw_input()`, and assuming the user is using Python 3, `input()` doesn't need the quotes to read a string. Agreed that the first `else` statement is misleading. Under the current logic, the user can get "access granted" with the wrong username but correct password.

Comment: Nice catch. I've corrected that above. That is an interesting caveat. Since I'm using 2.7, it's still sensitive to using strings, hence my explanation above.

Comment: I have that, if the 'if' is correct, then it will print out a capitol E, if it does not, then it will print out a lowercase e. (also I'm using python 3.3 and 3.7)